# UITextField and UILabel updating problem

Tags: iphone

I have two classes, one with textField and button and other is with label. These two classes have different views. 
I want to fill text in textField and save it with button press. I want to show the updation on  label. But it does not do it dynamically or side by side.

Label keep on showing same values or i have to restart the iPhone simulator.

Any suggestion?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to set up the class with the Label to be the Delegate for the Class with the TextField & Button... however if you added some code to your question it might be easier to help give you a specific answer.

Comment: class with TextField and button    -(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender{

 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:field1.text forKey:@"field1Key"];
 [defaults setObject:field2.text forKey:@"field2Key" ];
 [defaults setObject:field3.text forKey:@"field3Key"]; 
}

Comment: class with label:---// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated   {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ConfirmController" owner:self options:nil ];
    labelName.text=field1.text;
    labelPhone.text=field3.text;
    labelEmail.text=field2.text;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }

Comment: It would be easier if the code was in your Question, not in the comments of my 'answer'...

Comment: Anyway, in the buttonPress you're saving the text fields into the UserDefaults... but you need a way for these changed values to set the Labels. As I said, you'll probably need to set up ClassWithLabel to be a Delegate of ClassWithTextFieldAndButton. But I can't be more specific than that without seeing more of the code.